# How to access widgets defined in one class in other classes without seeing the graphical interface being redefined

Tags: python, class, tkinter, text, widget

I have a graphical interface with several frames, in the third I have a TKINTER TEXT widget allowing me to display text files after processing, when I  update this field from another class, it works but each time I lose the display of the 2 other frames (where te widget text is not present), what can I do to prevent this from happening?

the code for change the text :

```
data ='test of writing'
instance = TroisiemeUI(self)
instance.changeText(data)
```

the  definition of the principal GUI :

```
class MyWindow(Tk):
@catch_all_and_log
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.create_menu_bar()
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # Créer les volets et les cadres
        self.vertical_pane = ttk.PanedWindow(self, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.vertical_pane.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nEsW")
        self.horizontal_pane = ttk.PanedWindow(self.vertical_pane, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.vertical_pane.add(self.horizontal_pane)
        self.form_frame = ttk.Labelframe(self.horizontal_pane, text="Supervision")
        self.form_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.horizontal_pane.add(self.form_frame, weight=1)
        self.console_frame = ttk.Labelframe(self.horizontal_pane, text="Console")
        self.console_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=50)
        self.console_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=50)
        self.horizontal_pane.add(self.console_frame, weight=50)
        self.troisieme_frame = ttk.Labelframe(self.vertical_pane, text="Navigation")
        # visu_frame=ttk.Labelframe(vertical_pane, text="Visualisation")
        self.vertical_pane.add(self.troisieme_frame, weight=1)
        # Initialize all frames
        self.form = FormUi(self.form_frame)
        self.console = ConsoleUi(self.console_frame)
        self.third = TroisiemeUI(self.troisieme_frame)
...
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.quit)
        self.bind('<Control-q>', self.quit)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.quit)
        #fin
        self.geometry("1200x400")
...
def default_operation_EM(self):
       ...
            # read the text file and show its content on the Text
            data ='test of writing'
            instance = TroisiemeUI(self)
            instance.changeText(data)
```

the class where the method changeText is define  :

```
class TroisiemeUI:
              
    def __init__(self, parent):
        '''
        Constructeur
        '''
        self.parent = parent 
        self.creat_zone_info()
        self.creat_arborescence()
        self.creat_titre()
                                 
    def creat_zone_info(self):    
        # Texte edition
        self.texto = tk.Text(self.parent, height=14)
        self.texto.grid(column=2, row=0,padx=3, sticky='e')
        
    def changeText(self,nvtexte):
        # test = getattr(self.parent,'texto')
         self.texto.insert('1.0',nvtexte)
```

Comment: Some of your indentation looks broken. Also, this seems like far too much code. Please try to condense it down to a [mcve].

Comment: I don't understand your problem. And I can't run it so it impossible to help.

Comment: I don't know what you try to do but you should create instace only once and later change value always in this instance - but it seems you always create new instace so you doesn't access original content. In code you create `self.third = TroisiemeUI(...)` so later you should use `self.third.changeText(data)`. And if you want to access it in other class then create instance of first class and send it to other class as argument, assign to variable with `self.` and later use this variable to update original widget from first class.

Comment: Oh! thank you "Furas" !  I'm so happy after on  day of steril work you had find my solution...so simply ! :-) :            
            instance = self.third
            instance.changeText(data)

Answer (score 0):

I can't run code to see problem but I think you have problem because you create new instace of `TroisiemeUI` but you should use existing `self.third`

```
       def default_operation_EM(self):
            # read the text file and show its content on the Text

            data = 'test of writing'

            self.third.changeText(data)
```